# Ninject DependencyCreation and EventBroker extensions. Ensuring a one-to-one subscription

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc, ninject-extensions

I'm using Ninject Event Broker extensions and I have two services. `ServiceOne` is the Publisher of an event. `ServiceTwo` is the subscriber. `ServiceOne` doesn't have a hard dependency to `ServiceTwo`, I'm creating the dependency using the DependencyCreation extension.

Here are the requirements:

- I want to define a one-to-one event between these two objects. Only the `ServiceTwo` instance created by DependencyCreation should receive the event.
- If there are other instances of `ServiceTwo` further down in the object
  graph they shouldn't receive the event. (this shouldn't be the case
  but I want to account for it)
- `ServiceTwo` should be disposed of when `ServiceOne` is disposed.
- This is a web application and the life of `ServiceOne` should only be
  for one request.

Basically I'm just trying to recreate the behaviour of me writing:

```
var publisher = new Publisher();
var subscriber = new Subscriber();
var subscriber2 = new Subscriber();
publisher.MyEvent += subscriber.MyEventHandler;
```

One publisher. One subscriber. Subscriber2 doesn't get the event.

Here's my code:

```
this.Bind<IServiceOne, ServiceOne>().To<ServiceOne>().Named("ServiceOne").OwnsEventBroker("ServiceOne").RegisterOnEventBroker("ServiceOne");
this.Kernel.DefineDependency<IServiceOne, IServiceTwo>();
this.Bind<IServiceTwo>().To<ServiceTwo>().WhenParentNamed("ServiceOne").InDependencyCreatorScope().RegisterOnEventBroker("ServiceOne");
```

Two questions.

Does this fulfill my requirements? 
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally like to answer my own question but seeing as this has been quiet for a while, I've been testing my code sample and it appears to work fine. To clean up the creation of these dependencies and the whole event broker registration process I created some extension methods. First off an `IsPublisher` extension that creates a scoped event broker:

```
    public static ISubscriberBuildingSyntax IsPublisher<TPublisher>(this IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<TPublisher> syntax)
    {
        string name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        syntax.Named(name);
        syntax.OwnsEventBroker(name).RegisterOnEventBroker(name);
        return new SubscriberBuildingSyntax<TPublisher>(syntax, name);
    }
```

Secondly, a generic `CreateSubscriberDependency` method that creates a dependency using Dependency Creator:

```
    public ISubscriberBuildingSyntax CreateSubscriberDependency<TSubscriber>() where TSubscriber : class
    {
        this.syntax.Kernel.DefineDependency<TPublisher, TSubscriber>();
        this.syntax.Kernel.Bind<TSubscriber>().ToSelf().WhenParentNamed(this.name).InDependencyCreatorScope().RegisterOnEventBroker(this.name);
        return this;
    }
```

I can then call this like so:

```
     this.Bind<IRegistrationService>().To<RegistrationService>()
            .IsPublisher()
            .CreateSubscriberDependency<RoleService>();
```

This creates an Event Broker scoped to the `RegistrationService` instance with a `RoleService` dependency that is tied to the life of `RegistrationService`.

I can then register `RegistrationService` with `InRequestScope` to limit this to the life of one request.